# if statement after input wont compare to number

Tags: python

Im trying to write a program that asks every user for their age, if they are less than 16 years old it should remove them from the list.

Problem is i keep getting the following error - "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Even though i made sure the input is an "int", my "if" statement will not let me compare it to a numerical value (if i < 16).

Any help would be appreciated, all of the solutions i found online say i must use the "int" before the input, but i already did.

```
list_names = ['Daniel', 'Samuel', 'Ruth', 'David']

for i in list_names:
    int(input('What is your age? '))

    if i < 16:
        list_names.remove(i)
    print(list_names)
```

Comment: `i` references the name, not the age.  Store the age into a variable and perform the test on that variable.  Additionally, the list being iterated is *also* being edited, leading to unexpected behaviour.  Perhaps make a *copy* of the list and edit (or iterate) the *copy*.

Comment: I would do two things, change `i` to a more descriptive name, like `name`. Secondly, add the names to be removed to another list, then remove those names one by one at the end of your for loop.

Comment: list_names contains strings. What you are currently doing is trying to say for each name in the list, check if the name is less than 16. In other words, the first thing your program will do is check if 'Daniel' < 16, which doesn't make any sense. You should make it so that your program asks for the name of the user, stores it in a variable, then ask for the user's age, store the age in the variable as well. After that, check if the name that you saved in the variable is in that list_names, if it is -> check if the saved age is less than 16 and remove him from the list_names if that's true.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_names = ['Daniel', 'Samuel', 'Ruth', 'David']

for i in list_names:
    age = int(input('What is your age? '))

    if age < 16:
        list_names.remove(i)
    print(list_names)
```

you are comparing string with an integer. `i` is a string and 16 is an integer. So, your if condition does not work.

Also, you should save the input in a variable if you want to compare it. Just writing `int(input("..."))` will ask for input, but you won't be able to use it anywhere. That is why I saved it in `age`

Comment: Well shoot, now i feel dumb.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated!